# Tricky range based for loop implementation for an XML Element class in c++11

Tags: c++, foreach, c++11

How can I make something like this work with range based loops for both Elements and Attributes?

```
#include <list>
#include "XMLAttribute.h"

namespace XML
{
    class Element
    {
        private:
            typedef std::list<Attribute> attribute_container;
            typedef std::list<Element> element_container;

        public:
            XMLElement();

            bool has_attributes() const;
            bool has_elements() const;
            bool has_data() const;

            const std::string &name() const;
            const std::string &data() const;

        private:
            std::string _name;
            std::string _data;

            attribute_container _attributes;
            element_container _elements;
    };
}
```

I would like to be able to use something like:

```
for (XML::Element &el : element) { .. }
for (XML::Attribute &at : element) { .. }
```

And block something like `for (auto &some_name : element) { .. } //XML::Element or XML::Attribute?`.

Is it a good idea to implement it like this or should I change my design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is to give Element nodes functions that return ranges of child attributes and elements. Thus, you can do this:

```
for(auto &element : element.child_elements()) {...}
for(auto &attribute : element.attributes()) {...}
```

Your `child_elements` function would return some kind of type that stores two iterators, like a [boost::iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html). `attributes` would likewise return a range for attribute elements.